# How to create a function in Julia that has "varying constants"?

Tags: matrix, julia

Sorry, I know the question title is terrible, so let me exemplify. I am learning julia, and currently exploring matrix related codes. I am trying to calculate `eigenvalue` for a given matrix. SO I wrote this code:

```
using LinearAlgebra;
using Roots;

Δt(t) = det(t * I - Matrix{Int64}([4 2; 3 -1]));   # the matrix is hardCoded

# Calculate eigenvalues λᵢ
function calculateEigenValues()
  λ = find_zero(Δt, (1, 100))    
  println(λ)  # output = 5
end
```

So in this case, the matrix is hard-coded inside the characteristic equation, `Δt`. I wish to pass some matrix `A` as a parameter instead of hard-coding it, and so I wrote this:

```
using LinearAlgebra;
using Roots;
using Polynomials;

Δt1(t, A::Matrix{Int64}) = det(t * I - A) # Matrix{Int64}([4 2; 3 -1]));


function calculateEigenValuesV1()
  #dt = Δt(1, A)
  x = variable()  # from package Polynomials 
  A = Matrix{Int64}([4 2; 3 -1]);
  λ = find_zero(Δt1(x, A), (1, 100));  # crashes! no idea how to pass a value, and keep the other one as a variable
  println(λ)
end
```

And it does not work. I guess I am passing a variable, and a matrix in `Δt1`, and the output is a function. that function is set as the first parameter of `find_zero()`. How to write this correctly in julia?

[In case you're wondering, I've just learnt to use the builtin library, and that is not the problem. Sample code:

```
  A = Matrix{Int64}([4 2; 3 -1]);
  eigenValAndVec = eigen(A);

  A = Matrix{Int64}([4 2; 3 -1]);
  foo = eigen(A);
  foo.values; foo.vectors;  # <-- ok
```

I'm just curious about my error explained above.
]

Comment: just making sure you know that the LinearAlgebra library has eigenvalue and eigenvector functions already.

Comment: replace the `λ` line with `λ = find_zero(x->Δt1(x, A), (1, 100))` and remove the `x = variable()` line. The `find_zero` function expects a single parameter function, so the anonymous function defined `x->...` in the line, fixes the second matrix parameter (in functional programming parlance this is called currying).

Comment: @DanGetz thanks! I tried your code, and now it is working! :D

Comment: Furthermore, there's no reason to write `Matrix{Int64}([4 2; 3 -1])`. It just creates an extra unnecessary copy. Just write `A = [4 2; 3 -1]`.

Comment: @DNF You wrote the same comment in one of my previous questions. And like I said, I usually work with Java, kotlin, and c++. These languages have strict type checking, and I am used to it. Strict types help to eliminate accidental assigning an object to a different type of variable. Again, after one month or so, I'll forget what I was doing, but these notations help me to remembar what is going on. So these are 2 benifits of using strict types.

Comment: @QaziFahimFarhan In Julia nothing stops you from doing `A = Matrix{Int64}([4 2; 3 -1])`, and then doing `A = 10.0; A += 10`. What you want is this `A::Matrix{Int64} = [4 2; 3 -1]`.

Comment: @QaziFahimFarhan It's just a really unfortunate way of doing it, because it creates _two_ arrays instead of one. The best way is then actually `A = Int64[4 2; 3 -1]`. But it doesn't _accomplish_ anything better than `[4 2; 3 -1]`, and may give a false sense of security. Isn't it better to get used to idiomatic Julia instead of writing "C++ in Julia"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to recap the ideas from the comments (and possibly close this question). The following code is a more idiomatic Julia version of the OP code to find an eigenvalue (without using `eigen` from `LinearAlgebra` package):

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Roots

Δt1(t, A) = det(t * I - A)

function calculateEigenValuesV1(A)
    λ = find_zero(x->Δt1(x, A), (1, 100))
    return λ
end
```

After definining these functions, an example could go as:

```
julia> A = [4 2; 3 -1]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 4   2
 3  -1

julia> calculateEigenValuesV1(A)
5.0
```